# Is it possible to reduce Theory of Rationals to Theory of Natural Numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity, rational-numbers

Is the following possible ?
$$ Th( \mathbb{Q}, +, \leq ) \leq^{\log}_m Th( \mathbb{N}, +, \leq )$$

I believe it is not possible since Natural Numbers are not dense. It is also not possible 
$$ Th( \mathbb{N}, +, \leq ) \leq^{\log}_m Th( \mathbb{Q}, +, \leq )$$ since complexity of $Th( \mathbb{N}, +, \leq )$ is much higher than of $Th( \mathbb{R}, +, \leq )$

But I do not feel extreme confidence in my statement and "Googling" does not help to come up with anything more comprehensive than that.

Comment: What does "$\le_m^{log}$" mean?

Comment: @NoahSchweber logarithmic space reducibility